# Excel VBA - Copy andpaste formula without incrementing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of formulas similar to this one:

```
=MID('Sheet1'!O40,1,5)
```

I'm trying to copy and paste this formula to a blank cell without incrementing the cell reference and updating the worksheet reference.

Desired End Result:

```
=MID('Sheet2'!O40,1,5)
```

I've used the below code as a test sample but the copied formula auto increments the cell reference. Is there anyway to copy and paste formulas without incrementing?

```
Range("E2").Copy
Range("E126").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

Comment: So, are you sure that `'Sheet1'` of the original formula must be transformed in `'Sheet2'` in the target formula? You do not want cells incrementing, but you need Sheet name incrementing...?

Comment: I think we need more detail - is `Sheet2` the next sheet by index?

Comment: Correct. I don't want the cell references incrementing but I need to change the Sheet name on copy and paste of the formulas. With the test sample it automatically increments the cell references. Sheet 2 is next in index correct

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution below:

```
Range("E126").Formula = Range("E2").Formula
Set r = Range("E126").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
r.Replace What:="Sheet1", Replacement:="Sheet2", LookAt:=xlPart
```